# Mongod vs MongoDB server running as windows service

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find out what is the difference when i start mongod db with mongod command vs starting mongo db server as a windows service.
I tried starting the server using mongod and inserted some records then i tried starting mongo db via windows service and inserted some records, results are different in the same database

Comment: You're likely using different databases... different paths.  If you're sure you're not, then it could be any number of command line options.  You might even be using two different versions of MongoDB.  What differences are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Looks like these are different dbs, but i am unable to find the difference as names are same for the db which i am interested in . When I run 'show dbs', one has more dbs and i guess the reason is I have created more using windows service, but as I am still struggling to find out how these two ways create different dbs

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different databases.
And you likely checked the "install mongod as a service" in the installation.

The `mongod` command directory is, by default, `C:\data\db`.

If you setup your `mongod` Windows service directory to any other directory, this means you potentially have two databases (data folder).

You can search for the file named mongod.lock. If you find the file on different directory. you have more than one mongo database.